# How to display table installments only on the product page

Tags: php, magento

I managed to get a table in installments on the product page exactly where I wanted, was perfect, just below the special price. Added code table by modifying the file: app -> design -> frontend -> default -> default -> template -> catalog -> product -> price.phtml

It turns out that the table is showing up in other places, specifically on the homepage and the list of products, etc ... and wish to limit the appearance of the table only the product page. How can I do this? Inside the price.phtml or would be in another file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the catalog/product/view.phtml file instead. This handles just the product view page and it includes the price block from here. Better to create a custom block for your table and include your block on the product view.phtml file. See this guide on how to create a custom block. http://www.gravitywell.co.uk/blog/post/how-to-creating-your-own-custom-block-in-magento